# MariaDB/mySQL is there a way to limit a user to SELECT and SHOW queries?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have a support team member who we'd like to limit his access to our database. He has never caused any problems with UPDATE or DELETE but we'd like to limit him to SELECT/SHOW/etc if it's possible. Is there a way? I'm not talking about limiting the number of queries, but the *types* of queries he can run.

Comment: Have you tried [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GRANT to give them the exact authority that you would like them to have. It sounds like they may only need SELECT. For global authority use:

`GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'supportmember'@'localhost';`

Or limit the authority to a specific database using:

`GRANT SELECT ON specificdatabase.* TO 'supportmember'@'localhost';`

Or to a specific table in a specific database:

`GRANT SELECT ON specificdatabase.specifictable TO 'supportmember'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Dave's answer, if you would like to give this user the equivalent of [SHOW VARIABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html) then you would give him `SELECT` on [Performance Schema System Variable Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-system-variable-tables.html) too.

If there is a more limited subset of data you would like him to see, then you can [create views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) that execute as the *definer* and give him `SELECT` on the view only, so he would have no access to the underlying tables. This would enable you to filter by rows too if necessary.